# Is there a way to append left-indented text in a doc using Google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I'm trying to append a text in a doc via apps script, but I want the text to start from a specified left indent, and also have subsequent lines aligned with the indent. Currently, I'm using \t to tab the first line, but subsequent lines start on indent 0. I would appreciate if anyone could help figure it out.

Example:

```
body.appendParagraph('').setLineSpacing(1.5).appendText('\t\t' + 'mylongtext').setItalic(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the available paragraph classes here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph you will need to edit your code as follows:

```
body.appendParagraph('').setLineSpacing(1.5).setIndentFirstLine(50).setIndentStart(50).appendText('mylongtext').setItalic(true);
```

Adjust the number in the () as needed for setIndentFirstLine and setIndentStart, which is in pixels.